# Remove duplicated in base Unique JSONObjects in JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

How Remove duplicated **`JSONObjects`** in **`JSONArray`** java android

I have this code and I do not know how to remove duplicates, according to the duplicate value of number and time of arrays strings objects, but but I do not know how to do it, I'm a bit confused with arrays

```
 [
    {
        "isChecked": true,
        "name": "weber",
        "number": "+1912123456789",
        "time": "28 nov., 08:06 PM",
        "type": "all"
    },
    {
        "isChecked": true,
        "name": "weber",
        "number": "+1912123456789",
        "time": "28 nov., 08:06 PM",
        "type": "all"
    },
    //Duplicatedhowremovethisifnumberisequalandtime{
        "isChecked": true,
        "name": "weber",
        "number": "+1912123456789",
        "time": "28 nov., 08:07 PM",
        "type": "all"
    }
]
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Why not using `HashSet` ??

Comment: You need to validate one parameter that should not be the same first you need to decide what can be the unique value of any property

Comment: Yes i do with hashSet but only set one result and it erases the others, it's as if they were all duplicated

Answer (score 0):

JSON parser by default allows duplicates so there is no direct way to remove the duplicates. However, there are ways to deal with this. You can validate JSON against schema.

If using Jackson, here is the setting which will help you to detect duplicates:

```
     final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     mapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use set data structure. Set store unique objects. If you have custom objects, you need to override equals method and hash code method.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, i shared you

```
    String getloglist = sp.getString(Constant.LOG, "");

    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        // Load the data from json
        JSONArray jsonArraylogs= new JSONArray(getloglist);

        if (jsonArraylogs != null) {
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArraylogs.length();i++){
                listdata.add(jsonArraylogs.getString(i));
                //Toast.makeText(context, ""+listdata+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Toast.makeText(context, ""+listdata+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
    hashSet.addAll(listdata);
    listdata.clear();
    listdata.addAll(hashSet);

    Toast.makeText(context, ""+listdata+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```